# How to disable robots.txt when you launch scrapy shell?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, robots.txt, scrapy-shell

I use Scrapy shell without problems with several websites, but I find problems when the robots (robots.txt) does not allow access to a site.
How can I disable robots detection by Scrapy (ignored the existence)?
Thank you in advance.
**I'm not talking about the project created by Scrapy, but Scrapy shell command: `scrapy shell 'www.example.com'`**

Comment: could you share the logs you are getting when executing the shell command?

Comment: Logs : http://pastebin.com/MASXrYb9

Comment: logs show that you are definitely inside a Scrapy project, which means that a `settings.py` file is available

Comment: Because of the robots I do not acer to "response": 
[s] response <200 http://azertyuiop.com>
It is necessary to review the log to understand.
Another thing I work with is the "Scrapy shell" command and not with Scrapy project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the settings.py file of your scrapy project, look for **ROBOTSTXT_OBEY** and set it to **False**.

Comment: I modified the settings.py file then I run the command and the scrapy shell has price considering the change for all the others.
Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you run scrapy from project directory `scrapy shell` will use the projects `settings.py`. If you run outside of the project scrapy will use default settings. However you can override and add settings via `--set` flag.
So to turn off `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` setting you can simply:

```
scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False"
```

Comment: When I run this command, I have an error: 
http://pastebin.com/fwVsU4BB

Comment: Scrapy shell command checks the current spiders searching for their `allowed_domains` to match that spider attributes and custom settings for the current shell session. There could be a problem with one of those spiders.